# Submit Button Value Vanishes

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I'm having trouble with a button.  I make a relatively simple change to an echo line and suddenly the button I have, to submit a form, has a blank value.  It's only when I make this change.  Yes, I know about the duplicate IDs of "submit" but this isn't my code and that works correctly on another page that uses duplicate IDs.

```
echo "<div id='divswipe'>
  <p><input type='text' name='".$count3."' id='swipe' maxlength='7' /> <label for='swipe'>Please Enter User's ULID</label></p>
</div>
<p><input id='swipe' type='submit' value='Submit' /></p></form>";
```

This code will display the value of "Submit" with no problem.

```
 echo "<div id='divswipe'>
    <p><label for='swipe'>Please Enter User's ULID</label></p>
    <p><input type='text'  name='".$count3."' id='swipe' maxlength='7' /> <input id='swipe' type='submit' value='Submit' /></p>
</div></form>";
```

If I change it to this, the value for the submit value is blank.  It is very odd.  I can provide the CSS for the information above if that helps.  I have attempted to Google why the submit button's value disappears at the display of the page but found no information.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**EDIT**
Disregard.  I apologize.  I found the problem.  The guy who coded the page added some jQuery to it which in turn was blanking the value of IDs by the name of swipe.  Since he made two input types share "swipe" as the ID, it was blanking the value of the correct one while blanking the value of the button as well.  I added a ",:submit" to the section of his jQuery that excludes non-text input types (i.e. it ignores radio, checkboxes, selects, and now, submit buttons as well).  It works.  I apologize if I've wasted anyone's time!

Comment: Please clarify, which is it that works, the top one?

Comment: FWIW, you shouldn't give your text and submit button the same id ('swipe').

Comment: Yeah, right now the IDs are the same, like I said, because it's another guy's code.  I'm styling the pages he produces and I've told him about the duplicate IDs.  He needs them that way for logic right now but there is talk about re-doing the logic to fix that problem.

The top code = code that works fine.  The second code block is the code that nixes the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form data is based on names, not IDs. Give the submit element (technically input element of type submit) a name.

Edit: I think I misunderstood the question. If the problem is that the text on the button is not appearing, make sure the HTML validates.  It's likely a mismatched quote. It could also be CSS that is smashing down the width of the button or somehow transforming the text. Maybe try using Chrome's debugging panel, or Firebug in Firefox to examine the styling of the button.

Comment: That did not work.  I assigned the submit a name='submitbutton' and it still removes the value from the button.  This might be a PHP issue with logic elsewhere.  I'm just the designer but I figured an HTML change to code in order to match a different location would be easier!

Comment: I use Firebug which is how I saw the code is literally displaying on the page as value="".  It completely removes the value of the submit button when the page is rendered but I cannot find out why.  I added a width:100px to the button submit for just this page and it made the button wider but failed to display anything.

Comment: That definitely sounds like a mismatched quote caused issue.  Can you copy and paste a small segment of the output to a new page and see if it displays correctly?  If it does, then it's almost definitely a quote issue (or at least something to do with invalid html somewhere).

Comment: I apologize for wasting your time, Corbin.  Thank you for trying but, as you can see from my edit, I resolved the problem with some jQuery the other guy had snuck in.  Thank you for trying, however.